# LibGDX ProgressBar don't work

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I try to implement in my Game a ProgressBar for a Level Bar but it do not want work with my Code.

```
    Texture progressbar_background = new Texture("progressbar_background.png");
    Texture progressbar_knob = new Texture("progressbar_knob.png");

    ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle progressBarStyle = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle();
    progressBarStyle.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(progressbar_background));
    progressBarStyle.knob = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(progressbar_knob));
    ProgressBar level_progressBar = new ProgressBar(0,100,1,true,progressBarStyle);
    level_progressBar.setSize(500, 50);
    level_progressBar.setValue(1);
    level_progressBar.validate();
    stage.addActor(level_progressBar);
```

The problem is, the progressbar dont stretch the textures so the progressbar is very small on the screen but i set the size on 500px but on the screen it is mayby 100px or smaller, and the knob is not at the left in progressbar rather in the middle, and if i change the value it show nothing everything remains. please explain me how is my fail or explain me how does progressbar widget work. i surf in the internet but i dont find a actually example or tutorial.

Comment: Are you calling `stage.act()` in every frame?

Comment: no but i try it and it change nothing. it is still so small and the button is in the middle

Comment: are you changing the progress bar value?

Comment: yes, i can change it in everything, it remains the same

Comment: i think i need a good example or tutorial for ProgressBar in libgdx

Comment: have anyone a good example ?